# Can sites built with DW be worked on without DW?

Tags: adobe, computer-science, dreamweaver

I've got a prospect whose site was just built, but the forms don't work. The forms seem to be using a DW Extension. We don't build in DW, so I'm not familiar with how it works. If a site is built in DW, is it limited to only DW-related fixes/solutions?

Answer (score 2):

Dreamweaver is just a GUI for designing and developing HTML (etc;) pages, sites.

Many devs actually utilize nothing more than an enhanced Notepad application (like Notepad++).  Personally I consider Dreamweaver a crutch for people that develop in it from day 1, you take it away and they don't know anything because they rely on the program.  Which is fine for most work until they run into issue where they have to solve a problem themselves.

I don't hate dreamweaver, I just don't use it as my Notepad++ is sufficient for all my PHP, HTML, CSS, JSP, etc dev

**Extension**

You probably mean, a javascript library of some sort to validate the forms?  If so you could gut those out (or keep them) and use jQuery, or anything you are comfy with.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, absolutely.  Once Dreamweaver generates the code anyone who is familiar with whatever language it is in can work on the file.  Dreamweaver itself is not required for anything, but if you do use it you can take advantage of the wizards and what not.

But any text editor can edit pages generated by WP.

One note of caution: DW uses regular expressions to check its code and look for patterns that correspond to the various wizards.  If you edit the code, it may break that check and the behavior will no longer appear in the appropriate panel.  Everything will still work fine but you will no longer be able to edit via wizards.